# Angular removing elements from a list shared with a service

Tags: javascript, angular, concurrency

this problem is driving me crazy.

I have an array defined within a service, which is used in 3 other components:

This is the service, file products.service.ts (notice the product array of Products)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ​​HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Product } from './../models/Product';
import { ProductForm, productFormToProduct } from './../models/ProductForm';


// @Injectable({
//   providedIn: 'root'
// })

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/products';

@Injectable()

export class ProductsService {

  public products: Product[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProducts() {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl)
  }

  deleteProduct(p: Product) {
    // this.products = this.products.filter(prod => prod.id !== p.id);
    const i = this.products.indexOf(p);
    this.products.splice(i,1);
    return this.http.delete(apiUrl + "/" + p.id)
  }

  storeNewProduct(pf: ProductForm) {
    const idList = this.products.map((x) => {return x.id});
    const i = Math.max(...idList) + 1;
    const p = productFormToProduct(pf);
    p.id = i;
    this.products.push(p);
    return this.http.post(apiUrl, p)
  }

}
```

This is the component where i subscribe to getProducts, and fill the array (file products.component.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ProductsService } from '../../shared/services/products.service';
import { Product } from '../../shared/models/Product';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.scss']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[] = [];
  searchText: string = "";

  constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productsService.getProducts()
      .subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
        this.productsService.products = data;
        this.products = this.productsService.products;
      })
  }

}
```

And this is the component where i subscribe to deleteProduct (file product-card.component.ts):

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ProductsService } from '../../services/products.service';
import { Product } from './../../models/Product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.scss']
})
export class ProductCardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  @Input() product: Product

  public buttonDeleteFunction() {
    this.productsService.deleteProduct(this.product).subscribe();
  }


}
```

The problem is, when i click on some delete product button, i have this weird behaviour:

**Before click:**
[image]

**After click:**
[image]

Here is the products.component.html file:

```
<div class="products__header">
  <h3 class="products__heading">
    Listado de productos ({{ products.length }})
  </h3>
  <input
    class="products__search"
    placeholder="Buscador"
    type="search"
    [(ngModel)]="searchText"
  />
</div>

<p *ngFor="let p of products">{{ p.name }}</p>
<p>{{ products }}</p>

<div class="products__list">
  <app-product-card
    *ngFor="let p of products | filterNames: searchText"
    [product]="p"
  ></app-product-card>
</div>
```

**Why do i get the expected behaviour in only two of the four places where i use the products list?**

I know i can use an Output to manually remove the item from the list when i click the button, but i have been told that services are used instead of Inputs/Outputs when i want to share between multiple components, so i'd rather not use an Output for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use your approach with common data on service layer then a common pitfall is that Angular does not detect the changes that affect your component. In that case you must inform your component for those changes using an emmiter.

Use an emmiter on service

```
   productUpdated :EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

 deleteProduct(p: Product) {
    // this.products = this.products.filter(prod => prod.id !== p.id);
    const i = this.products.indexOf(p);
    this.products.splice(i,1);

    this.productUpdated.emit(this.products);

    return this.http.delete(apiUrl + "/" + p.id)
  }
```

And then listen for that change ProductsComponent

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[] = [];
  searchText: string = "";

  constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productsService.getProducts()
      .subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
        this.productsService.products = data;
        this.products = this.productsService.products;
      })
    this.productsService.productUpdated.subscribe( (data) => { 
      this.products = data;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Perfect, this works! i accepted and upvoted your answer.
However, i still don't understand why some of the html reflected the change while other didn't in my previous code.